# Change opacity of an image via drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, opacity, addeventlistener

I have to use a drop down menu which includes percentages from 0%-100% to change the opacity of an image, as I have only started using javascript this week (and am ideally supposed to use addEventListeners) I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: Yes, you might want to listen to the `change` event using `addEventListener`. More info about this method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work if you can use jQuery.

```
$(document).on('change', '#task3control') { 
var percent = $(this).find('option:selected').text().replace('%', '');
var decimal = parseFloat(percent) / 100; 
$('#tardis').css('opacity', decimal);
});
```

Comment: @Jeremy isn't using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="task3control" id="task3control" onchange="opacity();">
     ....
</select>
```

if you add the value to each `option` it can be done like this:

```
function opacity()
{
    var task3control = document.getElementById("task3control");
    setOpacity(
        document.getElementById("tardis"),
        task3control.options[task3control.selectedIndex].value
    );    
}

function setOpacity(tardis, value)
{
    tardis.style.opacity = "." + value;
    tardis.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + value + ")";
}
```

---

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/4zBpC/**

Answer (score 0):

First of all your options need values for example like this

```
<select name="task3control" id="task3control">
    <option>Select One</option>
    <option value="0.0">0%</option>
    <option value="0.1">10%</option>
    <option value="0.2">20%</option>    
    <option value="0.3">30%</option>
    <option value="0.4">40%</option>
    <option value="0.5">50%</option>
    <option value="0.6">60%</option>
    <option value="0.7">70%</option>
    <option value="0.8">80%</option>
    <option value="0.9">90%</option>                            
    <option value="1.0">100%</option>
</select>
```

Then just use this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var image = jQuery('img#tardis')
    jQuery('#task3control').on('change', function(event) {
        var opacityValue = parseFloat(jQuery(this).val());
        image.fadeTo('fast', opacityValue);
    });
});
```

I added fadeTo() for fancyness :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change it using *jQuery* **.fadeTo()** method which can also give you a motion when updating the opacity of the image.

**jQuery :**

```
$("#task3control").change(function(){
    var opacityValue = ($(this).val().replace("%", ""))/100; 
    $("#tardis").fadeTo("slow", opacityValue);
});
```

To make the opacity changed immediately just replace the **.fadeTo("slow", opacityValue)** with **.fadeTo("fast", opacityValue)** .

It can also be done using *javaScript*. Simply get the index of selected option using **selectedIndex** property and using that index get the value of the selected option.Then change the value of the image using that value.

**javaScript :**

```
task3control.onchange = function UpdateOpacity(){
    var element = document.getElementById("task3control");
    var opacityValue = (element.options[element.selectedIndex].value.replace("%", ""))/100;
    var myImage = document.getElementById("tardis");
    myImage.style.opacity = opacityValue;
};
```

[**Demo : jQuery**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/ufDZE/)

[**Demo : javaScript**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/jurcT/)